# cakephp 3.0 pagescontroller.php creates issue

Tags: cakephp

Have to create one module "pages" in cakephp 3.0

So, from console i have created "cake bake model pages"

after that i have created "cake bake controller pages" to create controller

Then, it says there is an already "pagesController.php" so i have created another "pagesController.php" file and write the code of default "pagescontroller.php" file.( there is an one function in old file display() so ihave just copy it from that file and pasted in newly created file)

Now when i access http://my-project/pages it does not redirect "index" action
it executes display() function. Also have created entry in routes.php for default entry and all that but not changed anything.

So my question is that how can i execute index() action for my pages module.

cakephp version 3.0

Comment: OK i solved that by changing controller and model name so no more name conflict.. BUT BUT BUT


**BUT STILL WAITING FOR ANOTHER SOLUTION PLEASE**

I want an another solution that's why i haven't marked it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

### Define a route to do what you want

The [default routes file](https://github.com/cakephp/app/blob/master/config/routes.php) contains this:

```
$routes->connect('/pages/*', ['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'display']);
```

That matches any url which starts with `/pages/` *including* `/pages`.

If you want the url `/pages` to reach your pages index action simply add a route for it, before the standard catch-all route:

```
$routes->connect('/pages', ['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'index']);
$routes->connect('/pages/*', ['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'display']);
```